# Pine lowest return NAN

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Have problems with understanding pine scripting.
Why does debug1 return NaN and debug2 return the right value.
Also have similar problems in other scripts when some var lose their value and return NaN

```
//@version=5
indicator("TEST")
plot(close)

debug1(txt) =>
    var table d = table.new(position.bottom_right, 1, 1)
    table.cell(d, 0, 0, txt, text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.teal)

debug2(txt) =>
    var table d = table.new(position.bottom_center, 1, 1)
    table.cell(d, 0, 0, txt, text_halign = text.align_left, bgcolor = color.teal)


if barstate.islast
    debug1(str.tostring(ta.highest(high,229)[288]))
    
debug2(str.tostring(ta.highest(high,229)[288]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting `NaN` because you called `ta.highest()` in the local scope only once (when `barstate.islast` is true). There is no highest value, because you have only 1 value.

This will help:

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Execution_model.html#execution-of-pine-script-functions-and-historical-context-inside-function-blocks